# Unit Test Graphics

Tags: java, unit-testing, graphics, junit

Is there a standard best-practice for unit testing code that generates graphics?  I am working specifically with Java and jUnit, but I think the concept would apply in other languages as well.

So far, the best that I can come up with is using Mockito to mock the `Graphics` object and assert pre-calculated things such as (pseudocode):

```
assert that graphics.drawString was called with ("abc", 50, 100)
assert that graphics.setBackgroundColor was called with Color.RED
```

While this is all well and good, I was wondering if this is the right way to go about it or if there are more established practices for testing graphical code.

Comment: did you consider getting the image from the graphics and compare with an image file read from resources?

Comment: @guido - That is a good suggestion I haven't explored.  Definitely worth a look.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is established practice, but I would consider an [SVGGraphics2D](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/svggen/SVGGraphics2D.html) from the Batik project for mocking Graphics, and comparing the generated [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) files.

The advantage over comparing binary files is that SVG files are relatively readable XML files, so if the two files are not equal, you not only know that there is a problem, but also you get a good hint about the exact place of the problem.

The advantage over your solution is that these SVG files can be viewed (for example in a browser), so the tested scenario is self-documented.

Comment: I will have to take a look into this class.  I like the sound of comparing xml files as opposed to raw graphics contexts.

Answer (score 2):

You  could use something like Mockito, and mock your graphics object.  Then you can verify that the methods drawString and setBackgroundColor  were called. Taking some examples from [here](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#1)

Something like:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;


Graphics graphics= mock(Graphics.class);
//Run you code .... 

//verification that the methods were called 

verify(mockedList).drawString ("abc", 50, 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

as you mentioned, you can test your calculations and calling graphics api. that's easy. but checking if you are using the graphics api correctly (and produce the correct picture), can be really difficult. i know some companies make screenshots of the generated graphics (e.g. web page) and compare it with expected result using many complex metrics. but usually it's not a way to reduce cost but some manager's yearly goal (let's say 'process automation'). so think twice before you go this way - usually it's not worth the pain